# Azure Vnet Peering initiated state when run with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, vnet

I deployed vnet peerings with terraform. But it was stuck on initiated status. When i tried manually with same values there was no problem. How can i fix it?

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "spoke_aks_peering" {
  virtual_network_name         = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network_spoke.name
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group_spoke.name
  remote_virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.virtual_network_aks.id
  name                         = "peerspoketoaks"
  allow_virtual_network_access = true
  allow_forwarded_traffic      = true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create a peering between 2 virtual networks:**

> Note: If the **Peering Status** is currently **Initiated** status in Vnet peering,kindly enable the peering on both Vnets to get the status connected.

To resolve the Issue, create peering on both the **VNet**, like below.

```
#Azure Virtual Network peering between Virtual Network stagingtotest and testtostaging
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peeringconnection1" {
      name                      = "stagingtotest"
      resource_group_name       = local.resource_group_name
      virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.network["staging"].name
      remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.network["test"].id
    }
   
   #Azure Virtual Network peering between Virtual Network testtostaging  and stagingtotest 
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "peeringconnection2" {
      name                      = "testtostaging"
      resource_group_name       = local.resource_group_name
      virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.network["test"].name
      remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.network["staging"].id
    }
```

[image]

**After Terraform apply**, Peering created on both the **Vnets**.

[image]

Refer the document   [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_peering) for more.